# Python ggplot: how to change color in geom_point?

Tags: python-3.x, python-ggplot

I would like to produce something with this kind of legend:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ggplot2.org](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_point-4.png))</sub>

(taken from R ggplot) but

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes('mpg', 'qsec')) + geom_point(aes(colour = 'qsec'))
```

gives me as an error

```
failed: ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "17.82"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "17.82" cannot convert argument to rgb sequence
```

Should I somehow preprocess the numbers? If so, how?

Comment: That looks like a bug :-( https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/331